# Why Kotlin Type Inference Working Different in Different Scopes?

Tags: kotlin, type-inference

When I declare a variable in global scope:

```kotlin
//global scope
val name: String = "sevban" //here there is no warning about explicit type redundancy
```

The compiler does not complain about explicit type redundancy while I declare a local variable in a function it does :

```kotlin
//in a function
fun foo() {
    val name: String = "sevban" //it does complain about explicit type redundancy
}
```

What is the reason for that differences ? Why type inference looking like its working haphazard ?

Answer (score 0):

We can probably only speculate since their decision is not explained in the documentation, unless this has been discussed on their issues list on YouTrack.

But I assume it's because in the global scope, there is a likely reason to need be explicit about the type: changing the type can break code in other files that is using the property. For example, in your code above, seeing that you have publicly exposed it as a String might make you hesitate to change it to some other kind of CharSequence without checking other code that it might impact.

For a local variable in a function, there's less of a concern about breaking code by changing the type, because the broken code would be within the same function you're working on. Explicitly putting the type when it's an exact match for what is inferred could be considered cluttering your code and making it less readable, although that's a matter of opinion.

This reason doesn't make sense for your third code example, but at least in Kotlin 1.8.21, I don't see this warning. They may have noticed that it shouldn't be a warning more recently than in the version you are using.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, you are right, the last sample does not fit to the situation. I will edit my question. Your thoughts are appreciated thank you.